# how to get data of other table in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and i am working on the project where i want to retrieve the full details of address table including city name, state name and country name.

In routes following is the code.

```
$addresses = App\Address::with('countries', 'states','cities')->get();
return $addresses;
```

when i am running the code i get an error

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::countries()
```

Please help me.

**cities table**

```
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states');
        $table->string('cityName', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**states Table**

```
 Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
            $table->string('stateName', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**countries Table**

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('countryName', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**addresses Table**

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states');
            $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
            $table->string('firstLine', 50);
            $table->string('secondLine', 50);
            $table->string('thirdLine', 50);
            $table->string('zipCode', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and in models
**City**

```
 class City extends Model
    {
        // City belongs to a State
        public function city(){
            return $this->hasOne('App\State');
        }

        public function address(){
            return $this->belongsTo('Address');
        }
    }
```

**State**

```
    class State extends Model
    {
        // State has many Cities
        public function cities(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\City');
        }

        // State belongs to a Country
        public function country(){
            return $this->hasOne('App\Country');
        }

    public function address(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }
}
```

**Country**

```
    class Country extends Model
    {
        // Country has many States
        public function states(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\State');
        }

        public function address(){
            return $this->belongsTo('Address');
        }

}
```

**Address**

```
class Address extends Model
{
    // Address has one City
    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\City','city_id');
    }

    // Address has one State
    public function states(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\State','state_id');
    }

    // Address has one Country
    public function countries(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Country','country_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at your State model, it dosent have countries relationship it has country relation, so do State::with('country')

Comment: sir but my method name is 'countries' in Address Model. still i have changed it as you have told it and getting error 
QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.state_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where `countries`.`state_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: Your Address model doesn't matter because you are using the `App\State` class, so you use the methods in that model when building relationships to that model.  Your `state` model should also probably `belongTo('App\Country')` which is why you are now getting another error.  It might help to re-read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I'm new to Laravel myself, and am actually working on an app with a similar relationship structure in terms of a sequence of hasMany / belongsTo models.  I have found that using Eloquent and the "::with()" is really clunky.  I wound up writing all of my queries in raw SQL using proper joins.

Comment: in model State change method country() like this return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');

Comment: thank you Amir Bar, user3158900,  Yurich. I am extremely sorry. I have changed the code  $addresses = App\State::with('countries', 'states','cities')->get(); to $addresses = App\Address::with('countries', 'states','cities')->get();. I want all data in address table. Thanks for your reply, Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Now that we can access all of a post's comments, let's define a
>   relationship to allow a comment to access its parent post. To define
>   the inverse of a hasMany relationship, define a relationship function
>   on the child model which calls the **belongsTo** method:

[Look One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

You have one Country has many states and inverse relation is the state has one country.
So you should in model State change method country() like this

```
public function country(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

and use `State::with('country')`

P.S.

And check the other models.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your answer. but by mistaken I had written wrong get query "$addresses = App\State::with('countries', 'states','cities')->get();
return $addresses;" and i have changed to  "$addresses = App\Address::with('countries', 'states','cities')->get();
return $addresses;". I want to get all city, state, country details related to Address

Comment: I showed you the rule. You just folow it and all will be ok.

Comment: i got the desire result by changing the relationship in my all model. Insted of  $this->belongsTo('Address'); in City,State and Country Model, I have added $this->hasOne('Address');  and in Address Model I have placed $this->belongsTo('App\City');, $this->belongsTo('App\State');, $this->belongsTo('App\Country');. i got all the related details of country, state, city in my address detail